# How to find the maximum value (rows) from a specific section of a column?

Tags: r, max, row, col

What flower(s) had the longest petals from the year 1980-1985?

```
subset(Garden$Year, subset = "Year" == 1980:1985)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We may subset the 'Year' with `%in%`, use the other column (not clear what the column name is - maybe 'petals') to subset and get the `max`

```
with(Garden, max(petals[Year %in% 1980:1985]))
```

`subset` works on a data.frame and not on a vector/column